# What is the ground clearance area required for certification for a blimp/airship that needs to be tethered?

Tags: ground-operations, airship

Does anyone know how much ground space needs to be allocated for keeping a blimp/airship tethered? I assume it is likely a circular area with the diameter being (2 x total length) + safety factor.

Comment: [Enough for it to swing around I presume](https://www.nytimes.com/2010/09/26/realestate/26scapes.html)

Comment: Are you asking for regulations or recommendations? Is there a specific country you're interested in?

Comment: The aircraft will most likely be operating in Europe but built in the U.S., from my understanding U.S. regulations typically translate almost everywhere. I'd love any insight on certification based on United States standards regarding this issue.